# Strange white bar appearing on some (mobile) devices

Tags: html, css

I can't get rid of some white bar on the right side of the screen. It shows only on some (mobile) devices, regardless of browser - but if you flip the screen into landscape mode it doesn't show anymore.

I have no clue what's going on, I checked all of the items sizes but there doesn't seem anything out of place.. Any help would be appreciated!

website: http://carlociarnelli.eu/

screenshots of the white space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxquc.jpg

Comment: I can't see a bar. Add a picture of it maybe.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LXABvoQ

here there are. it wouldn't let me post them

Comment: Not shows for me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little puzzle! First let me tell you how to make that puzzle yourself as a developer that you want to become, looking at your site! If you work in Chrome, go to F12 Dev tools, toggle the device tool bar and pick iPhone and/or others. You'll indeed see the evil white bar. In Firefox a similar workflow is available, but it's called responsive design mode and the button for it is on the right side (after pressing F12).

[image: Device toolbar]

The art is inspecting what elements are bigger than the page. Go with the inspector over the elements to see what is causing the overflow, e.g. due margin, padding, width, position etc. At first you may find the `<h1>Hi,</h1>` and `<h3>I am Carlo</h3>` elements, but then first inspect higher in the hiërarchie. You'll then find they are both in a class called `hero-content-area`:

[image: Inspecting element]

Notice how that class has a width of 400px, while the Galaxy S5 only has a width of 360px! As your page has a width of 100%, being 360px, that element gives you that 40px of whitespace.. Solution: Give *.hero-content-area* a `width: 100%` and you'll already notice the white bar is gone! Now throw out the `left: 50%` and `margin-left: 200px;` and you'll notice it's nicely centered again! ✔️

Another way of handling these things is specifying the minimum width in the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), located in your head. Currently it's `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. As you've now learned, the device-width can be as low as 375px or 360px, while your class is 400px. Solution: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=400, initial-scale=1.0">`. This would also solve your white bar issue! ✅

I hope you didn't mind me going in depth/to general, but at least you have your answer. :)

Comment: I really love how you showed everyone how to debug this *kind* of problem. Nice work.

Comment: Wow I don't deserve this answer